# C++ skip template instantiation for cases that don't satisfy requires clause

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm writing something like STL red-black tree for practicing coding.

My `TreeSet`, `TreeMap`, `TreeMultiSet`, `TreeMultiMap` all share implementation of `RedBlackTree`, whose declaration is like this:

```
template <Containable K, typename V, typename Comp, bool AllowDup>
requires std::invocable<Comp, K, K>
class RedBlackTree {
   // ...
};

template <Containable K, typename Comp = std::less<K>>
using TreeSet = RedBlackTree<K, K, Comp, false>;

template <Containable K, typename Comp = std::less<K>>
using TreeMultiSet = RedBlackTree<K, K, Comp, true>;

template <Containable K, Containable V, typename Comp = std::less<K>>
using TreeMap = RedBlackTree<K, std::pair<const K, V>, Comp, false>;

template <Containable K, Containable V, typename Comp = std::less<K>>
using TreeMultiMap = RedBlackTree<K, std::pair<const K, V>, Comp, true>;
```

I have a problem when writing `operator[]`, which should be instantiated only for `TreeMap` (this is the same as STL that provides `operator[]` only for `std::map` among four ordered associative containers)

My declaration is like this:

```
template <typename T>
  std::add_lvalue_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<V>().second)>
  operator[](T&& raw_key) requires (!std::is_same_v<K, V> && !AllowDup)
```

But it fails to compile if `RedBlackTree` was instantiated as `TreeSet` (where `V = K` so `!std::is_same_v<K, V>` does not hold).

The compiler's complain is that `V = K = int` (because I instantiated `RedBlackTree` as `TreeSet<int>`), so `V` does not have `second`.

Why the compiler doesn't skip instantiation of this function? `requires` clause isn't satisfied...

Compiler: MSVC 19.30

Comment: Since `V` is not a `pair`, `std::declval<V>().second` will produces a hard error.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Yes, but I'm instantiating it as ```V = K```, so ```!std::is_same_v<V, K>``` is false, I'm wondering why the compiler still tries to instantiate this function even if ```requires``` clause is false

Comment: @Jarod42 Both ```auto operator[](T&& raw_key) -> typename V::second_type& requires(!std::is_same_v<K, V> && !AllowDup)``` and ```typename V::second_type& operator[](T&& raw_key) requires(!std::is_same_v<K, V> && !AllowDup)``` give compile error. ```decltype(auto)``` compiles but it doesn't return lvalue reference. The only solution I've found so far was ```auto& operator[](T&& raw_key) requires (!std::is_same_v<K, V> && !AllowDup)```.

Comment: SFINAE only applies to direct context, `V` is fixed by class, it is not a member template parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`V` is fixed by the class, so you cannot use SFINAE on it in member function.

You might introduce extra template parameter as workaround:

```
template <typename V2 = V, typename T>
std::add_lvalue_reference_t<typename V2::second_type>
operator[](T&& raw_key) requires (!std::is_same_v<K, V> && !AllowDup);
```

or use `auto`/`decltype(auto)`

```
template <typename V2 = V, typename T>
auto& operator[](T&& raw_key) requires (!std::is_same_v<K, V> && !AllowDup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer:

I found that this solves the problem:

```
template <typename T>
  auto& operator[](T&& raw_key) requires (!std::is_same_v<K, V> && !AllowDup)
```